# Why does increasing UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE increases function call latency?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, performance

I did some experiment recently using a simple node.js server that executes an async crypto function (`crypto.randomFill()`) and tested it out on my 4CPU, 4GB raspberry pi 4.

```
const cryptoFillAsync = (bufferSize) => {
console.log('executing crypto fill async');

const buf = Buffer.alloc(bufferSize);

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    randomFill(buf, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('err filling async', err);
            reject(err);
        }
        console.log('Buffer filled');
        resolve();
    })
})
```

}

source code can be found here: https://github.com/jaanhio/is-nodejs-single-or-multithreaded/blob/main/server/main.js

I started the application on my rpi4 and observed how latency varies with the `UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE`.

This was what I got:

```
|   | min latency (s) | max latency (s) | avg latency of 9 requests (s) |
|---|---|---|---|
| size = 2  |  4.928 | 24.362  | 13.548  |
| size = 3 |  4.912 | 14.667  | 9.794  |
| size = 4  |  4.926 | 14.728  |  8.248 |
| size = 5  |  5.546 | 11.321  | 8.343  |
| size = 6  |  6.180 | 12.115  |  8.884 |
| size = 9  |  10.976 | 11.145  | 11.069  |
```

My question is: why does increasing `UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE` increases the min latency?

I thought it could be due to context switching and checked `/proc/$PID/status`. Indeed context switching increased with threadpool size but i also read that there shouldn't be any performance regression due to it, instead i should be wary of low threadpool size.

what exactly could be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

The readings are expected, as crypto is a CPU intensive work and nodejs uses libuv's threadpool to do the operations and return callback when the work is done.
You have 4 CPUs and I am assuming it will be 4 logical cores as well. So when size is

2: Then you are not fully utilizing the CPUs on your machine and max latency is high

3: You are using another CPU for processing and hence the max latency has decreased, but remember that you have 4 CPUs and one thread is used by the event loop as well. So you are using all your CPUs(kind of).

4: Not much difference from 3 as the same CPUs are being used for crypto operations as 3 UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE (not actually)

5,6,7,8: You have asked to spawn more threads than hardware limit. As resources are less, the threads will compete with each other and this increases the overhead of context switching, hence increasing the latencies.